# How to make an animation-list show up on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking at the documentation for [animation-list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) and the XML layout is straight forward, but I am confused how they deal with it in the code.

In that page they have something like:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
 img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

 // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```

But they never reference spinning_wheel_image anywhere in the XML they show, nor the spin_animation ....the id for the spin snippet in their examples is "selected"

So I am wondering where those two references come from?  And why the actual id of the XML snippet which is "selected" is never used?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I put my animations xml into a file called animation.xml

And in the code now I have this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);

        // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

        // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
        frameAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But they never reference spinning_wheel_image anywhere in the xml they show

`spinning_wheel_image` is the ID of an `ImageView`, presumably from a layout resource used with `setContentView()` or a `LayoutInflater`.

> nor the spin_animation ....the id for the spin snippet in their examples is "selected"

That is presumably a typo -- there is no `android:id` for `AnimationDrawable`. At least, it is not in the documentation. The name of an animation resource is based on the filename, and the filename is `spin_animation .xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Animation is not related to any view until you explicitly assign it to. It just defines certain set of transitions to be done. Then you select your view and apply animation to it. This lets you i.e. apply the same animation to many views. You may want to move your animation XML file to `res/anim` folder.